# SqlAlchemy + fastApi trying to join many - to - many tables

Tags: sql, join, sqlalchemy, fastapi

1st table "release_name":

|code|name|

|:---|:--:|

|1---|SOME|

|2---|ANY |

...

2nd table "release_value":
|code|name|

|:---|:--:|

|1---|SOME|

|2---|ANY |

...

3rd Is a table to make a join 2 tables above "release_code_name":

|release_name_code|release_value_code|

|:----------------|:----------------:|

|1----------------|2-----------------|

|1----------------|2-----------------|

|2----------------|3-----------------|

I'm using SQLAlchemy with FastApi. What I need to do is to join 2 tables in one by 3rd map table.

What I've tried at it doesn't print me what I need:

```
Link = Table(
    "release_code_name",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("release_name_code", Integer, ForeignKey("release_name_code.code"), primary_key=True),
    Column("release_value_code", Integer, ForeignKey("release_value_code.code"), primary_key=True),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint("release_name_code", "release_value_code")
)



class ReleaseNames(Base):
    __tablename__="release_name"

    code = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    build_name = relationship("BuildNames", secondary="release_code_name", back_populates="release_name")

class BuildNames(Base):
    __tablename__ = "release_value"

    code = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    release_name = relationship(ReleaseNames, secondary="release_code_name", back_populates="build_name")

@router.get("/")
async def build_names_by_release(release_name: str, db: Session = Depends(get_database_session)):
   result = db.query(ReleaseNames).join(BuildNames, ReleaseNames.build_name)
   return result
```

I think I have an issue on joining tables in controller function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `relationship`, `secondary` doesn't take a string but the variable containing your Table:

```py
build_name = relationship("BuildNames", secondary=Link, back_populates="release_name")
```

```py
release_name = relationship("ReleaseNames", secondary=Link, back_populates="build_name")
```

In the creation of your table, in `ForeignKey`, you pass a wrong parameter. Indeed, you gave it `release_name_code.code` instead of `release_name.code` .
You want to link your Column to the Table `release_name` and not to your column `release_name_code` (that you are creating right now).

`release_name_code` is the name of the column you are creating.
`release_name` is your Table `ReleaseNames`.

So replace the ForeignKey of your Table as follows:

```py
Column("release_name_code", Integer, ForeignKey("release_name.code"), primary_key=True),
Column("release_value_code", Integer, ForeignKey("release_value.code"), primary_key=True),
```

Comment: thanx for reply and digging into the problem. Fixed it, but got error as sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ReleaseNames.build_name - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'release_code_name'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.

Comment: Thank you. No errors. I hope one more last thing is that it returns me just a table of "ReleaseNames". I'm this query isn't right "db.query(ReleaseNames).join(BuildNames, ReleaseNames.build_name).all()"

Comment: If the answer provided is correct, I invite you to validate my answer.
Regarding your query, if you want to get `BuildNames` in addition to `ReleaseNames`, you must include it in your query, as follows: `db.query(ReleaseNames, BuildNames).join(BuildNames, ReleaseNames.build_name)`

Comment: it worked !!!!!!!!! I've Benn doing it for 3 days. I'll validate anything for you!!!!

Comment: thank you very very much @fchancel. Let me know if you need anything else from my side !